# How can I show the roles for users in database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to show all the roles for only the users in the user table of my database on my view. How would I go about doing that? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this; adapt the approach as you need:

```
SELECT UserName, RoleName From MyUsers;
```

In your MVC controller:

```
List<User> users = MyDataLayer.GetUserRoles();
ViewBag.UserRoles = userRoles;
```

In your view:

```
<ul>
   @foreach (User u in ViewBag.UserRoles) {
     <li>User @u in Role(s) @String.Join(", ", u.Roles.ToArray()) </li>
   }
</ul>
```

I've made a lot of assumptions here:

- you're using Razor syntax
- you're using a SQL data source with a very simplified query.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a SqlDataLibrary with a SQLContactDAL. I don't know how to use methods from the DAL in another class and library. I have included the SqlDataLibrary in my references folder.

Comment: You'll have to adapt my example for use by your specific data access strategy.